# zurb foundation 6 manual setup - error Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script

Tags: node.js, apache

manual setup with zurb foundation 6 doesn't work.

my steps:
change to directory xampp/htdocs/test (test folder)
open command line and type: git clone https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template projectname
*name should be the same (=projectname)
i installed the needed dependencies: cd projectname npm install

my result in command line:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname>npm install
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.

> node-sass@3.13.1 install C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-59_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-59_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@9.2.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\projectname\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\test\projectname\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v9.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN The package gulp-autoprefixer is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\......\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-21T19_06_03_400Z-debug.log
```

more information:
git for windows 2.15.0
node js v9.2.0

*sorry for repeating posts - its my first one here

Answer (score 1):

`node-sass` does not provide binaries for all environments.
You have to run `npm i -g --production windows-build-tools` (which is just `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`)

https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools will install the dependencies for `node-gyp` like Python 2 to build `node-sass` from the source code.

> node-gyp is a cross-platform command-line tool written in Node.js for
>   compiling native addon modules for Node.js. It bundles the gyp project
>   used by the Chromium team and takes away the pain of dealing with the
>   various differences in build platforms. It is the replacement to the
>   node-waf program which is removed for node v0.8. If you have a native
>   addon for node that still has a wscript file, then you should
>   definitely add a binding.gyp file to support the latest versions of
>   node.

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp